# Как мне вызывать setTimeout в requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Пишу rpg игру, и надо сделать так, чтобы монстр бил игрока раз в секунду, но при вызове setTimeout, он выполняется 60 раз в секунду, как можно решить эту проблему подскажиту пожалуйста

```
import Camera from "../gameObjects/camera";
import Map from "../gameObjects/map";
import Player from "../gameObjects/player";
import Mob from "../gameObjects/mob";

import {keyDownListener, keyUpListener, movesControler} from "./methods/controler";


export default class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.keydown = {};

        this.cnv = document.querySelector("canvas");
        this.ctx = this.cnv.getContext("2d");

        this.w = this.cnv.width = innerWidth; // viewport width
        this.h = this.cnv.height = innerHeight; // viewport height
        this.velocityPlayerCamera = 1.4;

        this.player = new Player(this.ctx);
        this.camera = new Camera();
        this.map = new Map(this.ctx);
        this.fightStatus = false;

        this.keyDownListener = keyDownListener.bind(this);
        this.keyUpListener = keyUpListener.bind(this);
        this.movesControler = movesControler.bind(this);

        this.mapWidth = this.map.getSize().w;
        this.mapHeight = this.map.getSize().h;

        this.init();
    }
    init() {
        this.keyDownListener();
        this.keyUpListener();
        this.mob = new Mob(this.ctx);

        this.loop();
    }
    fight(){
        this.mob.beat(this.player);
    }
    draw() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
        for(let key in this.keydown){
            this.movesControler(key);
        }

        //draw map
        this.ctx.fillStyle = "#cdc";
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.w, this.h);
        this.map.draw(this.camera);
        
        //calculates
        this.fightStatus = this.mob.agression(this.player);

        setTimeout(()=>this.fight(),1000);

        //draw player
        this.player.draw(this.camera);

        //draw mobs
        
        this.mob.draw(this.camera);
    }
    loop() {
        this.draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
    }
}
```

Comment: В вашем случае лучше использовать ```setInterval``` раз надо избивать игрока раз минуту.

Comment: да я уже понял, но это сейчас не столь важно, мне надо понять как вызывать setInterval раз в секунду

Comment: и я думаю что отмерять время надо в самом классе монстра, а не в игровом

Comment: ```setInterval```  и так вызывается раз минуту или сколько там поставлено во втором аргументе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constructor() {
  this.keydown = {};
  this.timer = null;
  ...


  ...
  if (!this.timer)
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => { this.timer = null; this.fight(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Странно поначалу оно несколько таймаутов в стек кидало, а потом заработало, не понял что я изменил только. Спасибо